# How do I make my sanity studio update to reflect on my nextjs app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tailwind-css, next.js13, sanity

After setting up my sanity studio with the initial data it worked, but whenever i make a change and publish it, it still shows me my previous data in my next app. I even had to delete some data in the studio but the changes are not reflected in the next app

I tried running it on production mode

Answer (score 0):

Im still trying to figure this out also, i had this problem and then i changed something in the fetch code and it updated.

So basically when i change something in the fetch code it updates to the newest data.

I dont know why this is happening i think it has something to do with caching but i tried everything i saw and still it didn't change anything.